# Select row doesn't work correctly on mobile

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

I run into this issue when I test the ui-grid on mobile.
When I select a row, it select 2 rows at the same time but some time it just select only 1.
It only happens on mobile

Please see in this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/I3U8CcyDpdFX2eDfSfEB?p=info)

Comment: You have a bug that is only visible on a mobile device. Fix it.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I don't understand. Could you please explain more ? What only visible on a mobile device ?

Comment: I did not understand your Q. Could you please explain it more? …